# Meteor error: Full project wont display in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm having a problem getting Meteor to work. I'm not sure if I'm just missing some Meteor convention, but I don't think that is the case. I've created a new project with this file structure:

```
*client
  -signup.html
  -signup.js
  -main.html
  -main.js
*public
*server
  -accounts.js
```

There are some more .css files, but I didn't see the need to list them. My problem, is that when I run the server and visit the site on localhost, the main.html will load, but nothing in the body tags is rendered. I looked at the order that Meteor loads files, to see if maybe something wasn't loading right. Everything seemed ok.

I also looked at a couple github projects in meteor, cloned them, added the packages, and then ran them on my local machine. I get the same problem.

I also deployed to meteor's servers in case it was something with my local system, but the same thing happens with the deployed app.

Is there some convention or configuration that I am missing?

EDIT: Add contents of main.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Routed Auth</title>

</head>


<body>
    {{> header}}

    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div id="main" class="span12">
                    {{renderPage}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="spacer"></div>
    </div>

    {{> footer}}
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your main.html.

Comment: @GeoffreyBooth Added above

Comment: What do you get in in your javascript error console?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a router package. What about a very simple app? Try `meteor create --example leaderboard` and running the created Leaderboard app. Does it work on your system?

Comment: @Tarang There are quite a few errors for 'unsafe-eval' (not sure what that is. I'll have to look into that) and it's also saying 'Template is not defined' and 'Meteor is not defined'.

Comment: @GeoffreyBooth Yes. The leaderboard app does work, as well as newly created apps.

Comment: If the leaderboard app works, and your app's code isn't very complicated, then one or more of the packages you're adding are causing your troubles. In particular an obsolete router package could cause lots of failures; try using https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router if you aren't already. I would create a fresh app and copy your files into it and run it, then add packages one by one to see which one causes the app to crash.

Comment: That did the trick. I had a package that was causing problems. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept that. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I'll always take some rep points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(per comments above:)

If the leaderboard app works, and your app's code isn't very complicated, then one or more of the packages you're adding are causing your troubles. In particular an obsolete router package could cause lots of failures; try using [Iron Router](http://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) if you aren't already. I would create a fresh app and copy your files into it and run it, then add packages one by one to see which one causes the app to crash.